# Eclipse and Android application development

Tags: android, eclipse, guice, roboguice

I am trying to use Roboguice in my app, but no matter how i try to add the jars they don't seem to be added to the apk doesn't include the roboguice/guice jars.  What do I do?  using eclipse 3.5 and adt .9.9

Answer (score 2, accepted):

where did you put the jars?

I usually put 3rd party jars in the `lib` folder at the root of your Project folder (same level as `src`, `assets` etc) and they seem to get picked up when building the apk. Make sure in Eclipse you are referring to the jar from the `lib` folder as well!

Comment: Why doesn't ADT copy the files for us when we do a build or deploy =-(

Comment: do you get any error? ADT will only copy across the file if the content was changed (e.g. recompiled etc). Otherwise it just reopens the app from the phone/simulator.